# What happens to the momory of a char pointer when no pointer is being pointed at it?

Tags: c, pointers

And by that I mean something like this.

```
int8_t *pt1 = malloc(sizeof(int8_t) * 10);
int8_t *pt2 = malloc(sizeof(int8_t) * 10);

pt1 = pt2;
```

Here, pt1 has a memory assigned. But now it is being pointed at pt2. Then what happens to the memory that was assigned to pt1? And is there a way to free it even if you did not save its pointer value?

Comment: It's becoming a *memory leak*

Comment: You would need to use `realloc()` for that. In (nearly) any other situation, you probably want to declare `int8_t* const ptr1 = calloc(10, sizeof(int8_t));` to prevent this from happening inadvertently,

Comment: @Davislor can you elaborate? How can realloc be used for what? Because I do not see how it can be used to free malloced memory when the last reference to it has been lost.

Comment: @Yunnosch Oh, sorry, what I meant is that you sometimes do legitimately want to write `p1 = realloc( p1, current_size );` or the like. You can re-use a block of memory that way. But you hardly ever want to overwrite a pointer to dynamic memory   otherwise. There’s no advantage under a modern optimizing compiler to having one fewer pointer variable declared in scope, and a lot of risk of it not pointing to what you think it does. So you’re better off declaring the pointer immutable so the compiler will catch this kind of bug.  Setting it immediately also prevents uninitialized-pointer errors.

Answer (score 4):

The memory still belongs to your application, and you no longer have the address stored to free it. This is the root of all memory leaks.

Answer (score 3):

Your question has 2 parts:

1. > what happens to the memory that was assigned to pt1?

   The memory `pt1` was pointing becomes inaccessible - although the memory is still allocated. On the other hand, both `pt1` and `pt2` point to the same memory location. This causes the program to occupy more memory than it needs and uses (i.e- the memory location `pt1` was initially pointing - that location can't be used anymore, but still occupied by the program) - which is named as [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).
2. > is there a way to free it even if you did not save its pointer value?

   Before doing `pt1 = pt2;`, you should call the [`free()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) function like `free(pt1);`- which will de-allocate the memory location pointed by `pt1`.

Answer (score 0):

the memory is still occupied by the application unless until you free the memory allocation using the `free()`  function or memory leak occurs.
for above question you need to write like

```
  int8_t *pt1 = malloc(sizeof(int8_t) * 10);
  int8_t *pt2 = malloc(sizeof(int8_t) * 10);

  pt1 = pt2;
  free(pt2);
```

which will free the memory of pt2 .

In java this is taken care by Garbage Collector

Comment: You don't seem to discuss the leakage of the memory allocated by the first call to `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

The memory which is allocated by an application, in especially Linux like system, belongs to the application as long as application is running. So whatever memory your process has allocated will be taken from application's address space and for better memory utilization, application is expected to free the block if it no longer wants to use it. So, if an application keeps allocating memory without freeing, at one point of time, system may go out of address space and process will be killed for lack of memory. But, if application is terminated without freeing any memory block, that memory block is owned by parent process and cleanup routine is run to free up that memory block.

Comment: Not really true.  When the application exits, ALL of its' memory is returned to the system.  Note: forcing the system/OS to cleanup after your code is a VERY poor programming practice and (especially when writing applications that run for days/months/years (for instance a server or embedded application)

Comment: This is what I meant by cleanup routines.

Answer (score 0):

**It's called a Lost Heap-Dynamic Variable and It Causes a Memory-Leak**

## Lost Heap-Dynamic Variable

A lost heap-dynamic variable is an allocated heap-dynamic
variable that is no longer accessible to the user program. Such
variables are often called **garbage**, because they are not useful
for their original purpose, and they also **cannot be reallocated**
for some new use in the program. Lost heap-dynamic variables
are most often created by the following sequence of operations:

1. Pointer pt1 is set to point to a newly created heap-dynamic
   variable.
2. pt1 is later set to point to another newly created heap-dynamic
   variable.

The first heap-dynamic variable is **now inaccessible**, or lost.
This is sometimes called **memory leakage**. Memory leakage is
a problem, regardless of whether the language uses implicit or
explicit deallocation.

Source: Concepts of Programming Languages 10th - Robert W. Sebesta

Answer (score -1):

The OS will free the memory if you don't free it. 
BTW: shared_ptr will free the memory if no one use it.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm

Comment: The OS _may_ free the memory, when the program terminates. But it is terrible practice to rely on this; what about programs that run for extended periods of time? Also, the Boost libraries are C++, and hence irrelevant since this is tagged as a C question.